# Suddenly I cannot sideload an app in android studio to the android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I did something to my android studio/emulator and now when I try to sideload my app it constantly reboots.  The first two lines in logcat are:

```
studio.deploy  Could not get package user id: /system/bin/run-as: unknown package: com.xxx.yyy
studio.deploy  Could not find apks for this package: com.xxx.yyy
```

- I have deleted .gradle and .idea folders
- I have invalidated the cache and restarted
- I have run Build/clean project and Build/rebuild project

The app has worked in the past and I have gone back to a version that was working, but I am still getting this error.  I have not changed the application id, i.e., the manifest has remained unchanged.
I am at an absolute loss on how to fix this.

This is all on `Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1`